# Group Rows By Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2014

I'd like to know how many rows, for a user, exist within a certain number of seconds (like 10). So, given this data:

```
UserId  CreatedDate
4.........2017-01-11 01:40:19:077
4.........2017-01-11 01:40:19:437
4.........2017-01-11 01:40:20:077
4.........2017-01-11 01:50:19:077
4.........2017-01-11 02:40:19:077
4.........2017-01-11 02:40:19:437
4.........2017-01-11 02:40:20:077
4.........2017-01-11 02:40:20:437
4.........2017-01-11 02:40:21:077
4.........2017-01-11 02:40:22:077
4.........2017-01-11 02:40:23:077
4.........2017-01-11 03:15:19:077
4.........2017-01-11 03:40:19:077
4.........2017-01-11 04:40:19:077
```

The first three rows would be grouped together, and rows 5-11 would be grouped together (because they're all within 10 seconds of each other).

I tried something like this, but that only gives me rows in groupings of two. I'd like to know all rows within that 10-second range.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT UserId
        ,CreatedDate
        ,ISNULL(LAG(CreatedDate) OVER (Partition BY UserId ORDER BY CreatedDate), '1/1/2000') AS PriorCreatedDate
    FROM Foo
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE DATEDIFF(SECOND,PriorCreatedDate,CreatedDate) <= 1
ORDER BY UserId, CreatedDate
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What does "all within 10 seconds of each other" really mean?  If a row had he value `2017-01-11 01:50:00`, would it be in the first group?

Comment: The first group is around 1:40, so no, that would be 10 minutes later. It would also not go with 1:50:19, because that's 19 seconds later.

Comment: is every user's individual activity broken down to it's own ex: 10 second interval, or all based on the SAME Master 10 second basis.  completely different results

Comment: The 10-second interval is global.

Comment: @BobHorn . . . As you've specified the problem, this requires a recursive CTE -- and that is rather expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something along these lines...

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([UserId] int,[CreatedDate] datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (4,'2017-01-11 01:40:19:077')
,(4,'2017-01-11 01:40:19:437')
,(4,'2017-01-11 01:40:20:077')
,(4,'2017-01-11 01:50:19:077')
,(4,'2017-01-11 02:40:19:077')
,(4,'2017-01-11 02:40:19:437')
,(4,'2017-01-11 02:40:20:077')
,(4,'2017-01-11 02:40:20:437')
,(4,'2017-01-11 02:40:21:077')
,(4,'2017-01-11 02:40:22:077')
,(4,'2017-01-11 02:40:23:077')
,(4,'2017-01-11 03:15:19:077')
,(4,'2017-01-11 03:40:19:077')
,(4,'2017-01-11 04:40:19:077')

;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,Flg = case when datediff(SECOND,lag(CreatedDate,1,CreatedDate) over (Partition By UserID Order by CreatedDate),CreatedDate ) >=10 then 1 else 0 end
     From @YourTable
) 
Select UserID
      ,DateR1 = min(CreatedDate)
      ,DateR2 = max(CreatedDate)
      ,RecCnt = sum(1)
 From (Select *,Grp=sum(Flg) over (partition by UserID order by CreatedDate) From  cte ) A
 Group by UserID,Grp
```

**Returns**

```
UserID  DateR1                      DateR2                      RecCnt
4       2017-01-11 01:40:19.077     2017-01-11 01:40:20.077     3
4       2017-01-11 01:50:19.077     2017-01-11 01:50:19.077     1
4       2017-01-11 02:40:19.077     2017-01-11 02:40:23.077     7
4       2017-01-11 03:15:19.077     2017-01-11 03:15:19.077     1
4       2017-01-11 03:40:19.077     2017-01-11 03:40:19.077     1
4       2017-01-11 04:40:19.077     2017-01-11 04:40:19.077     1
```

> **EDIT - Requested Notes**

If you were to execute

```
;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,Flg = case when datediff(SECOND,lag(CreatedDate,1,CreatedDate) over (Partition By UserID Order by CreatedDate),CreatedDate ) >=10 then 1 else 0 end
     From @YourTable
) 
Select *
      ,Grp=sum(Flg) over (partition by UserID order by CreatedDate) 
From  cte
```

The results would be:

[image]

Notice the Flg and Grp columns.  The Grp column is essentially a running total of the Flg column.

Comment: Did you mean to use `MAX` for DateR2? What's Flg? What's DateR1? Date range 1?

Comment: @BobHorn  yes i did...  :0

Comment: This looks to be working. I'm not sure how just yet, lol, but I'm looking at it. Not that it matters, but I added this at the end, because it's really what I care about: ` HAVING SUM(1) > 10  ORDER BY SUM(1) DESC`

Comment: Is Flg short for flag?

Comment: I think this will work too. This is a group of solutions that are normally referred to as SQL ranking problems.  The basic idea is that you need to rank the rows by some criteria that isn't built into SQL.  If you were doing it by day/month/year you could just group by those increments but because you are grouping by "10 seconds increments" it's not as easy to work with. So the typical solution is to do something like a nested query that assigns the rank/ordering of the individual records and then the outer query does the grouping based on that rank.  So John's solution does it with a CTE.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Could you explain this part to me?
`Grp=sum(Flg) over (partition by UserID order by CreatedDate) From  cte`
It appears that the CTE sets the flag to 1 for the first record in each group. Why the above line though? What is that doing?

Comment: @BobHorn See the EDIT

Comment: Ahhhhhh... Every time there is a new #1 for Flag, the group number goes up, and the group number stays that way for the entire group, allowing us to group by it. This is mad genius stuff. Thank you.

Comment: @BobHorn BINGO.   We're all standing on the shoulders of giants.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This way have more performance:

```
SELECT UserId, Date = Min( --Min or any value in the group give the same value
    case when DATEDIFF(SECOND, PreviousDate, creationDate) <= 10 
        then creationDate
        else PreviousDate
        end
)

FROM (
SELECT *,
PreviousDate = LAG(CreatedDate, 1, CreatedDate) OVER (Partition BY UserId ORDER BY CreatedDate desc), 
FROM CTE
)

GROUP BY UserId, case when DATEDIFF(SECOND, PreviousDate, creationDate) <= 10 
        then creationDate
        else PreviousDate
        end
ORDER BY UserId, Date
```